# Print a newline using awk on windows using unix tools for Windows

Tags: windows, awk

I installed unix tools for windows, but I cannot print a newline using awk. I've tried all the switches: \n, but nothing seems to work. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

My input (c:\temp\servers.txt)"

```
123 0 1
234 1 1
```

this is my script :

```
for /F "tokens=1" %%A In (c:\temp\servers.txt) DO awk "$2 == "0" {print $6,\n }" input.txt
```

Comment: I think you are always going to have difficulties printing the 6th field of 3...

Comment: Don't subject yourself to Windows quoting hell. Install cygwin if at all possible. If not, save your awk script in a file and execute it as `awk -f file`.

Answer (score 2):

Windows is useless at accepting single quotes in command parameters - which means you need to put your `awk` commands inside double quotes on Windows, which means you can't use double quotes for `print` statements and strings - grrrr!

It is therefore easier to put your `awk` commands into a file called `script.awk` like this:

```
BEGIN{ORS="\r\n"}
$2==0{print $1}
```

That says... separate all output lines with Carriage Return + Linefeed (just how Windows likes things) and then, on any line where the second field is zero, print the first field.

Then do this:

```
awk -f script.awk C:\servers.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to print a newline is just to use `print ""`. The Output Record Separator `ORS` (which is a newline by default) will be appended to the empty string.

If you already have a `print` statement and want to add an additional newline to the output, you can use the `ORS` variable yourself, for example `print $6 ORS`.

This approach is more portable than hard-coding the characters "\r\n" or "\n" in your script, as the default value of the `ORS` should *just work* for the system that you are running on (i.e. it should already be "\r\n" on Windows and "\n" on most other systems).

Answer (score 0):

An example of printing a string that contains embedded newlines ;

the ‘\n’ is an escape sequence, used to represent the newline character

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "line one\nline two\nline three" }'
-| line one
-| line two
-| line three
```

Maybe this article will help you out abit more:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Print-Examples.html

There are multiple solutions to this problem, u can try and see which one suits best for you

Comment: Hi Shqiptar, Your example will work in bash, but it's not working on windows. I get a syntax error. Can you change my script and show me how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you have to use double quotes for the command line script, and you have to escape embedded double quotes with a backslash like this:

```
C:\Users\ReluctantBiosGuy>gawk "BEGIN{print \"line one\nline two\nline three\"}"
line one
line two
line three

C:\Users\ReluctantBiosGuy>
```

For your original script, I don't see why you are trying to use command.com's FOR command, nor is it clear what you really want to print. However, the following should give you enough info to do what you really want to do:

```
C:\Users\ReluctantBiosGuy>type x
123 4 5
132 0 4
153 0 33
384 3 88

C:\Users\ReluctantBiosGuy>gawk "$2==0{printf(\"Token 1 is %s\n\n\",$1)}" x
Token 1 is 132

Token 1 is 153


C:\Users\ReluctantBiosGuy>
```